# Prove the series of functions converges uniformly at $[-a,a]$ where $0<a<1$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2} \right) $$
>
> Prove the series converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{2}\log(x+1)$ at $[-a, a]$ where $0<a<1$.

I've noticed that $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \int_o^1 t^{2n} dt$. Hence,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \int_0^1 t^{2n}dt = \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^N t^{2n} dt = \\ \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1-t^{N+1}}{1-t} = \frac{1}{1-t} \lim_{N\to\infty}\left( \int_0^1 1 dt - \int_0^1 t^{N+1} dt\right) = \frac{1}{1-t} \left( 1- 0 \right) = \frac{1}{1-t}$$

Is that what I am supposed to do (or is there some sort of trick behind this question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 s\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{2n + 1}} - \frac{{x^{n + 1} }}{{2n + 2}}} \right)}  \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow s\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{2n + 1}}} \right)}  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{{x^{n + 1} }}{{n + 1}}} \right)}  \\ 
  \Rightarrow s'\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {x^{2n} }  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {x^n }  \\ 
  \Rightarrow s'\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{1 - x^{2n} }} - \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{1 - x^n }}} \right) = \frac{2}{{2\left( {1 - x^{2n} } \right)}} - \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{1 + x^n }}{{\left( {1 - x^n } \right)\left( {1 + x^n } \right)}}} \right) \\ 
  \Rightarrow s'\left( x \right) = \frac{{1 - x^n }}{{2\left( {1 - x^{2n} } \right)}} = \frac{1}{{2\left( {1 + x^n } \right)}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^n x^n }  \\ 
  \Rightarrow s\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\left( { - 1} \right)^n \frac{{x^{n + 1} }}{{n + 1}}} \right)}  \\ 
  \Rightarrow s\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left( {1 + x} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$